# Calculate area of a circle

Tags: circles, area

\begin{align}
π &= 3.1415\dotsc\\
s&= πr^2
\end{align}
Because $π$ infinitely continues, does it means $s$ is not ever a right answer, does it mean we do not know exact $s$ of a circle? Is there any other way that we find exact value of $s$?

Comment: $\pi$ is a number, not a series of decimal approximations.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "exact."  $9\pi$ is a perfectly exact area of a circle of radius $3$.

Comment: $s$ is always the right answer. We do know the exact value of the area of a circle - just because we can’t write down a finite decimal representation for it doesn’t mean it’s somehow _wrong_.

Comment: If by "exact" you mean *rational*, then there is no nonzero rational $r$ such that $s$ is rational. So what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the math universe, $\pi$ times $r$ squared is an exact number whenever $r$ is known. Real numbers result from a logical construction and $\pi$ is a well-defined thing.

In the physical world, there are no perfect circles nor any length that can be exactly measured and the question is irrelevant.

---

If for you "to find the exact value" means to enumerate the decimals, you will be dead long before a substantial number has been listed. In fact, this will never arise. On the other hand, $3.1416$ is a better-than-enough approximation for all real-life needs.

---

**Final remark:**

The area of a circle of radius $\dfrac1{\sqrt\pi}$ is exactly $1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is about how we represent numbers. The point is - as you know, ${\pi}$ is an irrational number. We cannot write it as a fraction, and thus we also cannot write down the full number as a decimal number. It is not going to be possible to write it out fully **in this form**.

Just because we cannot represent a number in a way we would like to, that doesn't mean the number "doesn't exist", and we have created these symbols to deal with the fact that numerical representation becomes a problem. Symbolic representation is much more powerful. If you want to represent the area (or $\pi$) as a decimal number, you are right in saying it will just be an approximation. And there is no way around that. We know $\pi$ is irrational.

Just as @Yves Daoust has pointed out though - in the real world, circles aren't perfect. So the area of any "real world" circle will never be actually known, using ${\pi r^2}$ means we are approximating the circle as a perfect Mathematical circle. This is also what they do in Physics - they do a lot of "assume this is perfect" approximations, but we still can quite accurately describe the world around us!